# Variational Equation in Perturbation Theory Chapter of Arnold *Geometric Methods in ODE*

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, variational-analysis

In the preface to Chapter 4 ``Perturbation Theory" in Arnold's book *Geometric Methods in the Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations* available for preview here

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387966496

he writes:

``If the size of the perturbation is characterized by a small parameter $\varepsilon$, then the effect of perturbations over time of order 1 leads to a change of order $\varepsilon$ of the solution.  This change can be calculated approximately by solving a variational equation along the unperturbed solution."

He then goes on to discuss the asymptotic methods necessary to discuss the validity of approximation at long times, but I am left wondering:

**Question:** What is the ``variational equation along the unperturbed solution'' referred to here?

I would guess that we are finding for finite time the next-order correction term in $\varepsilon$ to the leading order behavior (given by the solution of the unforced equation) but I am not sure about this and also not sure how this leads to a variational problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This is a name given to the (systems of) linear ODEs satisfied by the derivative of the solution operator with respect to initial conditions, parameters, etc.  For example, if $\varphi(\cdot)$ is a solution of a scalar ODE $x'=f(t,x)$ then the variational equation is $y'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,\varphi(t))y$.  A small piece of advice:  One should have a good command of the basic theory of ODEs before endeavoring to read V. I. Arnol'd's *Geometric Methods ...*.

Comment: thank you - I was confused because I expected the name "variational equation" to mean that the equation will come from the variational principle as Euler-Lagrange equations for some functional.  Does this interpretation hold?  and can you recommend a reference besides https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Variational_equations

Comment: Regarding the first question:  No, it has nothing to do with the calculus of variations (and nothing to do with the "variation of constants" either).  Perhaps there were some historical links, but I am not aware of them.

Comment: Now to the second:  I found it in J. K. Hale's [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=LdTZJ4HwCv4C&redir_esc=y), pp. 21-24 (but it is not mentioned in the index).

Comment: Ok great thank you for settling my first question, that was my main confusion